# SQL how to update a new column with statements for each row

Tags: mysql, sql

I've added a new column to the table "werknemer", the column is called "salaris_schaal".

I want in that column a int that can say what salary scale the employee ("werknemer") is. "Salaris" is the salary the employee haves.

A salary scale haves a minimum salary and a maximum salary, I made up this query with help from the internet (searching). And I think it's to closest I can get atm, I tried different queries but those didn't work.

```
UPDATE werknemer 
SET salaris_schaal = 
    CASE
       WHEN salaris > 700  and salaris < 1200 
         THEN salaris_schaal = 1 
       WHEN salaris > 1201 and salaris < 1400 
         THEN salaris_schaal = 2
       WHEN salaris > 1401 and salaris < 2000 
         THEN salaris_schaal = 3
       WHEN salaris > 2001 and salaris < 3000 
         THEN salaris_schaal = 4
       WHEN salaris > 3001 and salaris < 9999 
         THEN werknemer.salaris_schaal = 5
END
```

I've seen that its also possible to `SELECT` and `END as UPDATE` , is that a better way to manage this?

I am fairly new to SQL and program a lot in JAVA is it possible to use something like if and else statements in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, remove the assignment of `salaris_schaal` in each `THEN` of `Case` statement.

Try this syntax

```
UPDATE werknemer SET salaris_schaal = 
CASE
WHEN salaris > 700  and salaris < 1200 
THEN  1 
WHEN salaris > 1201 and salaris < 1400 
THEN  2
WHEN salaris > 1401 and salaris < 2000 
THEN 3
WHEN salaris > 2001 and salaris < 3000 
THEN  4
WHEN salaris > 3001 and salaris < 9999 
THEN  5
END
```

**Note:** When `salaris>=9999` or `salaris<=700` then `salaris_schaal` will be assigned with `NULL`

Comment: Thanks! worked as i intended!, i changed evry `<` to `<=`